# Presenting user information to a Profile page of a logged in user: Next.js, mongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I'm trying to create a profile page that will present the users full name, email, and password (in bullet points not the actual value). They can then change the password and this will be stored in the database for that user. To do this, would I need to create an API that will get the users information from the database? And is grabbing all the user sensitive information (password) from the database via an API standard practice or is there a better way of doing this?